# write list of dataframes to xls using WriteXLS

Tags: r, excel, export-to-excel

I'm having trouble finding the documentation to answer my seemingly straightforward question.

For simplicity's sake, I have a list of 3 dataframes of differing numbers of rows.

```
mylist<-list() 
mylist[[1]]<-c(1:10)
mylist[[2]]<-c(2:15)
mylist[[3]]<-c(20:54)
```

I'd like to write each element of the list to a separate sheet in an excel workbook, which I presumably can do with WriteXLS (?).

When I call

```
WriteXLS("mylist", ExcelFileName="mylist.xls")
Error in WriteXLS("mylist", ExcelFileName = "mylist.xls") : 
One or more of the objects named in 'x' is not a data frame or does not exist
```

... does WriteXLS not support lists? If not, how do I get around this efficiently? I will be writing files as part of a large simulation.

Answer (score 0):

I always create temporary data frames (rectangular arrays) ...

```
sheet0 <- data.frame(array.no.1)   # This is usually set of descriptions of the sheets
sheet1 <- data.frame(array.no.2)   # The data
sheet2 <- data.frame(array.no.3)   # More information 
myxls <- c(sheet0="Index",sheet1="Results",sheet2="Notes")

WriteXLS(names(myxls),ExcelFileName="my.xls",SheetNames=myxls)
```

The documentation says "data.frames" so that led me to this solution.